# JSON multi line with WooCommerce API

Tags: json, wordpress, woocommerce, multiline

I have tried a bunch of things to get this working.

```
text1\ntext2

text1\\ntext2

text1\r\ntext2
```

None of these work.

When I GET the JSON reply from the API after creating a product manually in wordpress with multiple lines it shows

```
<p>text1<\/p>\n<p>text2<\/p>
```

I cannot seem to reproduce this when creating a post with the API.
When trying to replicate this exactly I end up with

```
<p>text1 text2<\/p>\n
```

Which is not the desired result at all. I am only getting single line entries.

Answer (score 0):

```
"enable_html_description": true,
"enable_html_short_description": true
```

These values were added to the API docs.